# Read/Write params after call JasperFillManager.fillReport()

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to know if there is a way to get and set the params of the JasperPrint Class after the fillReport() method ?
I want to do something like this:

```java
JasperPrint print;

 Map<String, Object> params = getParams(); // fill the map of params

 print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                    configRequisicaoImpressao.getModeloImpressao(), params,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(gerarListaDeItens()));
```

I want to read/write the params from the variable print after call the fillReport method.